# Story about a nomad cursed to roam forever?

Tags: identification-request

There was a story that we read in my high school literature class Freshman year that I've been trying to find again, but for the life of me I can't remember the name of it.

The story was about a nomad that stopped in a town and ended up falling in love with a woman in the town. They were intent on being together and settling down but the nomad ends up leaving again, cursed to wander forever, after remembering an argument he had with his mother a long time ago where he told her he would run away and never stop running.

Does anybody have any idea what story this is?

Comment: When were you a freshman in highschool?

Comment: Maybe some version of the Wandering Jew? Many literary works  feature this legend.  Check out the (long) list on Wiki, see if anything sounds familiar.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandering_Jew

Comment: @bobble perhaps about a decade ago.

Comment: @Pete No, that's not it. There's nothing religious in the story and it's never even outright stated that the traveler is cursed, just heavily implied. I took a look at the list anyway but nothing looks familiar there.